# Set image programmatically on button

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I have issue with set-up image programmatically on button.
I have next WPF button:

```
<Button Name="MyBtn" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="FlashOnOf_Click" Height="256" Width="256" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
```

and try to set-up image on it with next cases:

```
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx://Assets/light_bulb_off.png"));
        brush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

        MyBtn.Background = brush;
```

one more case:

```
        MyBtn.Content = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx://Assets/light_bulb_off.png")),
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
            Height = 256,
            Width = 256
        };
```

Also with no luck. Any ideas where i've made mistake?

Answer (score 4):

You should set image like this:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn.Content = new Image
    {              
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/image/add.jpg", UriKind.Relative)),
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
        Height = 256,
        Width = 256
    };
}
```

where `Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/image/add.jpg"` is address to image and `WpfApplication` is the name of your WPF Application, `image` is the folder, `add.jpg` is the name of image.

The basic approach looks like this:

```
Button myButton = new Button
{
    Width = 50,
    Height = 50,
    Content = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image source")),
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the [UriKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on creating BitmapImage

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyBtn.Content = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Imagename.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
            Height = 256,
            Width = 256
        };
    }
```

Also please check your image using.

```
<Image Height="256" Width="256" Source="/Assets/Imagename.png" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't helps.

Comment: Have you changed the image name ? Just copy paste the code & rename  image

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that I am using '"ms-appx://' before 'Assets', otherwise I have 'System.ArgumentException' exeption.

Comment: It is working for me with the same code. put a background color to your button & check, Also check the Build Action property of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set image as button background,

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource=new Uri (@"C:/imagename.jpg",UriKind.Absolute);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            brush.ImageSource = bitmap;
            button.Background = brush;
          }
```

To set image as button content, try this.

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            button.Content = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/imagename.JPG", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
                Height = 256,
                Width = 256
            };
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue was in URI name:
Next line

```
Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx://Assets/light_bulb_off.png")),
```

should be changed to this:

```
Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/light_bulb_off.png", UriKind.Absolute)),
```